# How to show process in another already opened frame?

Tags: buffers, frames, process, focus

I have two frames opened in emacs (one in each monitor, but this is irrelevant). I would like to have a lisp function to switch the buffer in the other frame (in the other monitor), whose focus is in an arbitrary buffer. The buffer I want to switch to in the other frame has a process (say Python) that is already running. When doing this, I want to keep the final focus in the current frame and buffer I ran the lisp function. Only now the other frame will show the buffer with the process. How could I have a lisp function to do that?

Edited: I ended up doing this, but maybe there is a better way

```
(defun go-to-python-buffer ()
  "Create or visit a Python buffer."
  (interactive)
  (if (null (process-live-p (get-process "Python"))) ; (note that this line is different for python b/c get-process return different types in that case)
      (progn
        (split-window-sensibly (selected-window))
        (other-window 1)
        (run-python))
    (progn
      (split-window-sensibly (selected-window))
      (switch-to-buffer (process-buffer (get-process "Python")))
      (other-window -1)) ) )

(defun go-to-python-frame ()
  "Create or visit a Python buffer in another frame."
  (interactive)
  ;; check if there is a python process already open, if not, start one
  (if (not (stringp (get-process "Python"))) ; (note that this line is different for R b/c get-process return different types in that case)
      (run-python))
  (if (= (list-length (frame-list)) 1)
      ;; if there is just one frame, create another, put the focus, and show the buffer with the python process
      (progn
        (switch-to-buffer-other-frame (process-buffer (get-process "Python")))
        (other-window-or-frame -1))
    (progn
      ;; if there is another frame already open, show the python buffer, and keep the focus
      (select-frame (next-frame))
      (switch-to-buffer (process-buffer (get-process "Python")) )
      (other-window-or-frame -1))))
```

Comment: Does your frames have dedicated names to help us target the right one?  E.g., a frame for processes, a frame for code, a frame for email, a frame for calendar, etc. -- `(let ((a (make-frame '((name . "TODAY")))) (b (make-frame '((name . "TOMORROW"))))) (message "a: %s | b: %s" a b ))`

Comment: They don't, but we can give them arbitrary names when they are created, as you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from `emacs -q`, switch to the `*scratch*` buffer, copy and paste the example below to the `*scratch*` buffer, place the cursor immediately following the last closing parenthesis, and press:  `C-x C-e` (aka `eval-last-sexp`).  Then type `M-x my-example`

**STEP BY STEP**:

- Step #1:  Create or retrieve the process buffer (in this example we use `run-python`).

[The default behavior when `run-python` is executed is to display the process buffer in another window on the existing frame.  This example does not seek to alter the default behavior -- e.g., we are not deleting windows; we are not seeking to prevent windows from being split.]

- Step #2:  Make a new frame named **MISCELLANEOUS**.
- Step #3:  Make a new frame named **PROCESSES**.
- Step #4:  Cycle through all existing frames looking for the frame named **PROCESSES**.
- Step #5:  Display the process buffer in the largest window on the frame named **PROCESSES**.
- Step #6:  Select the original frame where the user was just before starting this example.
- Step #7:  Sit for just three (3) seconds and quickly observe what happened.
- Step #8:  Clean up the example by deleting the frame named **MISCELLANEOUS**.
- Step #9:  Clean up the example by deleting the frame named **PROCESSES**.
- Step #10:  Display a message thanking the user for trying out this example.

```lisp
(defun my-example ()
"Example for @Diogo."
(interactive)
  (let ((python-buffer
          (progn
            (require 'python)
            (or (python-shell-get-buffer)
                (process-buffer (run-python)))))
        (original-frame (selected-frame))
        (a (make-frame '((name . "MISCELLANEOUS")
                         (height . 20)
                         (width . 80)
                         (top . 0)
                         (left . 625))))
        (b (make-frame '((name . "PROCESSES")
                         (height . 20)
                         (width . 80)
                         (top . 400)
                         (left . 625))))
        (frame-list (frame-list)))
    (catch 'break
      (mapc
        (lambda (frame)
          (let ((frame-name
                  (cdr (assq 'name (frame-parameters frame)))))
            (when (and python-buffer (equal frame-name "PROCESSES"))
              (throw 'break (progn
                (with-selected-frame frame
                   (unless (get-buffer-window python-buffer)
                    (set-window-buffer (get-largest-window) python-buffer))))))))
        frame-list)
      ;; Just in case there was an error above, throw a break.
      (throw 'break nil))
    (select-frame original-frame 'norecord)
    (raise-frame original-frame)
    (sit-for 3)
    (delete-frame a)
    (delete-frame b)
    (message "Thank you for testing this example.")))
```

Comment: it works, but the other frame closes, and if there is a second frame already open, it does not use it. I ended up doing something in those lines that I posted in the edited question.

Comment: I've added a 10-step analysis to explain what this example does.  If you need additional assistance, please let me know.